# In C, why if(sizeof(int)>-1) gives false output?

Tags: c, if-statement, sizeof

```
if(sizeof(int)>-1)
{
printf("0");
}
else
{
printf("else");
}
```

it executes the else statement.
Why doesnt it follow the if part even if int size>-1.

Answer (score 2):

`sizoe(int)` yields an integer of type `size_t` which is unsigned integer. Due to [*usual arithmetic conversions*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8) in C, `-1` gets converted into a `size_t` and a hence, `-1` becomes SIZE_MAX. Obviously `sizeof(int)` is less than `SIZE_MAX` and the condition (`if`) is false.